# Lucky palindrome with longest prime number need help i couldn't able to do

Tags: javascript

A string is called a palindrome if it may be read the same way in either direction. For example, “12321” is a palindrome, but “12341” is not. A palindrome string can itself compose of one or more palindrome sub-strings. Now, your task is to find out the length (denoted by L) of the longest palindrome sub-string, maximum-length contiguous substring of a given 
string that is also a palindrome, and print "YES" if it is lucky otherwise print "NO". A palindrome sub-string is called lucky iff it's length is a prime number.
For example : Consider a string s =”122321”. The longest palindrome sub-strings in s is of length 3. Hence, you need to output "YES" (quotes only for clarity).

```
function solution(r) {
    if (r.match(/[a-z]/g) || r.match(/[A-Z]/g) || r.match(/[0-9]/g)) {
        for (var t = gettingPrimeList(r), o = "", n = 0; n < r.length; n++)
            for (var e = t.length; t > 0; t--) {
                var a = r.substr(n, t[e - 1]);
                console.log(a);
                for (var i = a.length; i > 0; i--) {
                    var g = a.substr(0, i);
                    console.log(g);
                    var s = g.split("").reverse().join("");
                    if (g == s) {
                        o = "YES";
                        break
                    }
                    o = "NO"
                }
            }
        return o
    }
}

function gettingPrimeList(r) {
    for (var t = [], o = 2; o <= r.length; o++) {
        for (var n = !1, e = 2; e <= o; e++) o % e == 0 && e !== o && (n = !0);
        !1 === n && t.push(o)
    }
    return t
}
alert(solution("random12321random"));
```

Comment: ...
function gettingPrimeList (S){
      var b = [];
       for (var count = 2; count <= S.length; count ++){
            var noPrime = false;   
      
       for (var i=2; i <= count; i++){
        if(count%i ===0 && i!== count){
            noPrime = true;    
        }
    }
    if(noPrime === false){
        b.push(count);       
    }
    
       }
       return b;
          
}

alert(solution("random12321random"));

Comment: function solution(r){if(r.match(/[a-z]/g)||r.match(/[A-Z]/g)||r.match(/[0-9]/g)){for(var t=gettingPrimeList(r),o="",n=0;n<r.length;n++)for(var e=t.length;t>0;t--){var a=r.substr(n,t[e-1]);console.log(a);for(var i=a.length;i>0;i--){var g=a.substr(0,i);console.log(g);var s=g.split("").reverse().join("");if(g==s){o="YES";break}o="NO"}}return o}}function gettingPrimeList(r){for(var t=[],o=2;o<=r.length;o++){for(var n=!1,e=2;e<=o;e++)o%e==0&&e!==o&&(n=!0);!1===n&&t.push(o)}return t}alert(solution("random12321random"));

Comment: i have posted the solution but it's not working can anyone please help me here

Comment: Please [edit] your question. Code in comments is unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in following steps:

- Create two function `isPrime()` to check if number is prime or not. Second to check if string is a palindrome or not.
- Get all the substrings starting from `str.length - 1` then `str.length - 2` and so on.
- The way to get substrings is that create a variable `l` which will be length of substring.
- Keep making substrings until the length of substring is greater than `1`.
- If the `while` loop create a nested for loop which will get all substrings.

**Note:** I am not sure that you want to check the whole string or not. If you want to check also the whole string then change `let l = str.length - 1;` to `let l = str.length;` in `check` function.

The code returns `true` and `false`. You can fix it according to your needs.

```js
function isPal(str){
  return [...str].reverse().join('') === str
}

function isPrime(num){
  if(num === 3 || num === 2) return true;
  if(num === 1) return false;
  if(num % 2 === 0) return false;
  
  for(let i = 3;i<Math.sqrt(num) + 1;i+=2){
    if(num % i === 0) return false;
  }
  return true;
}

function check(str){
  let l = str.length - 1;
  while(l>1){
    for(let i = 0;i<str.length-l;i++){
      let temp = str.slice(i,l);
      if(isPal(temp)) return isPrime(l)
    }
    l--;
  }
  return false;
}

console.log(check("122321")) //true
console.log(check("123454321")) // false
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function solution(S) {
    var max_length = 0,
    maxp = '';
    for(var i=0; i < S.length; i++){
        var subs = S.substr(i, S.length);
        for(var j=subs.length; j>=0; j--){
            var sub_subs_str = subs.substr(0, j);
            if (sub_subs_str.length <= 1)
            continue;

            if (is_Palindrome(sub_subs_str)){
                if (sub_subs_str.length > max_length){
                    max_length = sub_subs_str.length;
                    maxp = sub_subs_str;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    maxp = IsPrimeNumber(maxp.length);
    return maxp;
}

function is_Palindrome(S) {
    var rev = S.split("").reverse().join("");
    return S == rev;
}

function IsPrimeNumber(n){
  if (n===1){
    return "NO";
  }
  else if(n === 2){
    return "YES";
  }
  else{
    for(var x = 2; x < n; x++)
    {
      if(n % x === 0)
      {
        return "NO";
      }
    }
    return "YES";
  }
}

console.log(solution('random12321random'))
```